# Planned grocery stores in the US

Tags: data-request

I am looking for any data/information regarding new and planned grocery stores in the US. Or specifically the Pacific Northwest.

Answer (score 1):

Check out our [business data at Datafiniti](https://datafiniti.co/products/business-data/).  We don't have data on planned stores, but we do have location data for pretty much every grocery store in the US.

A call to our API like:

```
https://api.datafiniti.co/v4/businesses/search
{
    "query": "categories:(\"grocery store\" OR \"grocery stores\") AND country:US" 
}
```

returns 201,567 matches.

Here's an example record:

```
    {
        "address": "1551 W St Marys Rd",
        "categories": [
            "Grocery Store",
            "Grocery Stores"
        ],
        "city": "Tucson",
        "country": "US",
        "dateAdded": "2017-06-30T05:17:32Z",
        "dateUpdated": "2017-09-22T20:40:56Z",
        "hours": [
            {
                "day": "Monday - Sunday",
                "hour": "6:00 AM - 12:00 AM"
            }
        ],
        "keys": [
            "us/az/tucson/1551wstmarysrd/1858061378"
        ],
        "latitude": "32.2277",
        "longitude": "-110.9980",
        "name": "Safeway",
        "phones": [
            "5206248442"
        ],
        "postalCode": "85745",
        "province": "AZ",
        "websites": [
            "http://local.safeway.com/az/tucson-255.html"
        ],
        "id": "AVz3bszsFcQ3k02bDdBy"
    }
```